# Make Mathematica not to evaluate an integral?

Tags: output-formatting, expression-manipulation

I want the output to contain an integral, while everything under the integral sign evaluated. How can I prevent the system from evaluating the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) or [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) with [`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html).

With

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]
```

Then both

```
r1 = Inactive[Integrate][f[x], x]
```

and

```
r2 = Inactivate[Integrate[f[x], x], Integrate]
```

give

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The difference colour for the integral symbols shows they are inactivated. `Activate` all the `Inactive` symbols in both `r1` and `r2` with

```
Activate /@ {r1, r2}
```

> ```
> {-Cos[x], -Cos[x]}
> ```

Finer control of what is `Active` and `Inactive` with these functions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does not do anything for me. Still evaluates and gives beep on non-convergent integrals.

Comment: The variant r2 works though. I wonder, why r1 does not.

Comment: @Anixx These functions where introduced in version 10.  Which version are you using?  Check your spelling of the functions.

Comment: Using 12.3 r1 version does not work. R2 works as expected.

Comment: @Anixx I'm using 12.3.1 so could be a bug that has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Use this known trick

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]
g=HoldForm[Integrate[f[x], x]] /. HoldPattern[f[x]] :> RuleCondition[f[x]]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To evaluate, do `ReleaseHold[g]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]